# An algorithm for iteration over all values in a column of a table

Tags: algorithm, vba, loops, iteration, brute-force

I am looking for a simple algorithm which works on the following table:

[image]

In the first column you see the constraints. The second column should be used by the algorithm to output the iterations, which should be done like this:

```
 0  0  0
 0  0  1
........
 0  0 29
 0  1  0
........
 0  1 29
 0  2  0
 0  2  1
........
........
27  9 29
28  0  0
........
........
28  9 29
```

Currently I have the following code:

```
Dim wksSourceSheet As Worksheet
Set wksSourceSheet = Worksheets("Solver")

Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim lngLastColumn As Long

With wksSourceSheet 
    lngLastRow = IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)), _
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Rows.Count)
    lngLastColumn = IIf(IsEmpty(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count)), _
        .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, .Columns.Count)

    Dim intRowOuter As Integer
    Dim intRowInner As Integer
    For intRowOuter = 2 To lngLastRow
        .Cells(intRowOuter, lngLastColumn).Value = 0
    Next intRowOuter
    For intRowOuter = lngLastRow To 2 Step -1
        For intRowInner = lngLastRow To intRowOuter Step -1
            Dim constraint As Integer
            Dim intConstraintCounter As Integer
            intConstraint = .Cells(intRowInner, 1)
            For intConstraintCounter = 1 To intConstraint 
                .Cells(intRowInner, lngLastColumn).Value = intConstraintCounter
            Next intStampCounter
        Next intRowInner
    Next intRowOuter
End With
```

This might be a right approach but something is incorrect. I'm unfortunately stuck so I would appreciate some help on fixing this.

Comment: How many digits in total? Six as shown in the example?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you thinking about? Its ok if you don't have a solution, but you must have an idea of how to go about solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

I would suggest using one array to store the constraints and one to represent the counter.

```
Dim MaxNum() As Long
Dim myCounter() As Long
ReDim MaxNum(1 To NumDigits)
ReDim myCounter(1 To NumDigits)
```

Next you need to initialize `MaxNum`. This will probably involve looping through the cells containing the constraints. Something like:

```
Dim constraintRange As Range
Dim i As integer

Set constraintRange = wksSourceSheet.Range("A2:A4")
For i = 1 to numDigits
    MaxNum(i) = constraintRange.Cells(i,1).Value
Next i
```

Now we just need to write an increment counter function! The idea is pretty simple we just go from the least significant digit to the most significant. We increment the LSD and, if there is overflow we set it to 0 and then add 1 to the next digit. It looks like this:

```
Sub IncrNum(ByRef myNum() As Long, ByRef MaxNum() As Long) 
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(myNum) To UBound(myNum)
        myNum(i) = myNum(i) + 1
        If myNum(i) > MaxNum(i) Then 'Overflow!
            myNum(i) = 0 'Reset digit to 0 and continue 
        Else
            Exit For 'No overflow so we can just exit
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which is just one for-loop! I think this will be the cleanest solution :)

NOTE: To use this function you would simply do `IncrNum(myCounter, MaxNum)`. Which would change the value of `myCounter` to the next in the sequence. From here you can paste to a range by doing `dstRange = myCounter`.

### Testing

In my own tests I used a while loop to print out all of the values. It looked something like this:

```
Do While Not areEqual(MaxNum, myCounter)
    Call IncrNum(myCounter,MaxNum)
    outRange = myCounter
    Set outRange = outRange.Offset(1, 0)
Loop
```

`areEqual` is just a function which returns true if the parameters contain the same values. If you like I can provide my code otherwise I will leave it out to keep my answer as on track as it can be.

Comment: I am trying to adjust your solution to my application. First of all I am wondering that you are invoking your counter function like: `IncrNum(myCounter,MaxNum)`. I get syntax error in this case. I looked in a [manual](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/VBA_in_Excel/_Prozeduren#Unterprogramm_.28Sub.29) and discovered that the sub should be invoked like this: `Call IncrNum(myCounter,MaxNum)`

Comment: In the second place you say that you use only one for-loop. But since the counter function increments the counter only once I need to put this function in another loop. Furthermore I need to implement function `areEqual` which compares two arrays and I can't imagine how to do this without third loop. So we actially need 3 loops here. Do I get this right?

Comment: And  to write the array `myCounter` to the corresponding cells I need another loop.

Comment: As seen in the example you can simply do `outRange = myCounter` to write your array to a range. If you need every number from `0` to `MaxNum` you will need to do one iteration for every possible number; there is no avoiding that. Note that the `IncrNum` loop breaks early most of the time. This is more efficient than your loop. Lastly if you make a couple clever decisions when making `areEqual`, you can get it to exit on the first iteration most of the time. It will largely be  constant time operation!

Comment: @DannyLo also you are correct about the error in my code! I fixed my answer :)

Comment: I try the following: `Dim outRange As Range`, then `Set outRange = mySheet.Range("C2:C9")` and finally use it like you suppose: `outRange = myCounter`. If I debug into the do-while loop I see that every cell in `outRange` is set to myCounter(1) in every iteration.

Comment: @DannyLo Your array currently has dimensions 1x`NumDigits`. You are trying to ouput to a `NumDigits`x1 Range. To make sure the array is in the correct dimension use `outRange = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(myCounter)`.

Comment: Hm, that proposal doesn't works for me - the code outputs nothing. Proofpic: http://i.imgur.com/9mMxJjd.png

Comment: @DannyLo at this point this is really all the help I can give. The code I gave you works on my computer on both excel 2013 and excel 2007. I suggest doing some some research on excel forums for how to do this. If you cannot figure it out you should be able to adapt `IncrNum` to take a range instead of an array. Or you can just output using a for loop (it really does not make the code any less efficient)

Comment: Thanks, you already gave me a great help! I choose to output to the table using the loop of the counter function, since that method has the least impact on the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this can be modified to fit your needs. It simulates addition with carry:

```
Sub Clicker(MaxNums As Variant)
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, m As Long, n As Long
    Dim sum As Long, carry As Long
    Dim product As Long

    m = LBound(MaxNums)
    n = UBound(MaxNums)
    product = 1
    For i = m To n
        product = product * (1 + MaxNums(i))
    Next i
    ReDim A(1 To product, m To n)

    For j = m To n
        A(1, j) = 0
    Next j

    For i = 2 To product
        carry = 1
        For j = n To m Step -1
            sum = A(i - 1, j) + carry
            If sum > MaxNums(j) Then
                A(i, j) = 0
                carry = 1
            Else
                A(i, j) = sum
                carry = 0
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(product, n - m + 1)).Value = A
End Sub
```

Used like:

```
Sub test()
    Clicker Array(3, 2, 2)
End Sub
```

Which produces:

[image]

Comment: This seems like a good solution provided `product` fits into a `Long`! Note that you can do a slight optimization by exiting out of the inner for loop when the carry is 0 as I did in my answer :)

Comment: @MichaelSPriz I noticed that we posted very similar solutions almost simultaneously.  The details can vary but something along this line is clearly the way to go. I kept the inner loop the way it is since I still needed to pull the values from the row above it.

Comment: Very true! I missed that bit. Thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 0):

`x%10` or `x Mod 10` give the remainder when x is divided by 10 so you will get the last digit of x.

Since your problem is specifically asking for each digit not to exceed 463857. You can have a counter incrementing from 000000 to 463857 and only output/use the numbers the fullfill the following condition:

```
IF(x%10 <= 7 AND x%100 <=57 AND x%1000 <= 857 AND x%10000 <=3857 AND x%100000 <= 63857 AND x <= 463857) 
THEN //perform task.
```

Comment: Well I would accept solution in every language even pseudocode. It's about algorithm, not the implementation.

Comment: Yea he just edited the question..before he asked for a pseudocode example in any language. I'm editing my answer right now.

Comment: But I'm not sure how I could apply modulo operator to my case.

Comment: Unfortunately your proposal wouldn't work. I mentioned terms "number" and "digit" to simplify the understanding of my question. In the spreadsheet I have "cell" and "number", so a constraint can be >= 10.

Comment: I recommend editing your question to explain this. So each "digit" of the number is in a different cell? And each "digit" can be larger than 10?

Comment: I wrote the question almost from scratch to make it more precise. I hope it is more understandable now.